# Do the eigenvalues converge if hermitian matrices converge in Frobenius norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of complex hermitian $m\times m$ matrices that converges to another complex hermitian $m\times m$ matrix $A$ in the 
Frobenius norm, i.e. 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|A-A_n\|_{F}=0.$$
For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $\lambda^{(1)}_n\ge\cdots\ge\lambda^{(m)}_n$ be the ordered eigenvalues (they are real because of the spectral theorem) of $A_n$ and let $\lambda^{(1)}\ge\cdots\ge\lambda^{(m)}$ be the ordered eigenvalues of $A$.

Question: Do the eigenvalues converge in the sense that for each $j\in\{1,\dots,m\}$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \lambda^{(j)}_n=\lambda^{(j)}\quad\text{?}$$

Comment: And what do you think? Hint: equivalence of norms in finite-dimensioned spaces + continuous dependence of polynomial roots on the coefficients of this polynomial.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy The characteristic polynomials converge pointwise and hence the coefficients in any polynomial basis for degree $m$, but what do the roots do?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy They converge. I didn't know about this continuous dependence before.  Thanks very much!

Comment: @TZakrevskiy. Thank you. Could you please explain what effect ordering the eigenvalues in a matrix had on eigen value decomposition in the diagonal matrix?

Comment: @Avra I don't quite understand what you are asking. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy. Thank you for replying. What I am asking is, is there any effect for ordering the eigen values of the diagonal matrix when we do eigen value decomposition or it does not matter?

Comment: @Avra that's almost verbatim the same question, and I still do not understand what you need=) I guess the best course of action for your would be to post this a separate question - you'd gain visibiity